# Checking if values exist, and adding them to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

Here is my code (sorry about the formatting):

```
if row[0] == "":
    empty1 = "true"
    print "row[0] needs a Variable"
else:
    print "row[0] has Variable"

if row[1] == "":
    empty1 = "true"
    print "row[1] needs a Variable"
else:
    print "row[1] has Variable"

if row[2] == "":
    empty1 = "true"
    print "row[2] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[2] has Variable"

if row[3] == "":
    empty2 = "true"
    print "row[3] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[3] has Variable" 

if row[4] == "":
    empty3 = "true"
    print "row[4] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[4] has Variable" 

if row[5] == "":
    empty4 = "true"
    print "row[5] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[5] has Variable" 

if row[6] == "":
    empty5 = "true"
    print "row[6] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[6] has Variable" 

if row[7] == "":
    empty6 = "true"
    print "row[7] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[7] has Variable" 

if row[8] == "":
    empty7 = "true"
    print "row[8] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[8] has Variable" 

if row[9] == "":
    empty8 = "true"
    print "row[9] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[9] has Variable" 

if row[10] == "":
    empty9 = "true"
    print "row[10] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[10] has Variable"    

if row[11] == "":
    empty10 = "true"
    print "row[11] is Missing Variable"
else:
    print "row[11] has Variable"    

if row[12] == "":
    empty10 = "true"
    print "row[12] needs a Variable"
else:
    print "row[12] has Variable"    


myList = (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[12], row[12], row[0], row[12], row[12], row[12], row[0])

print(chunk % (myList))
```

What I am attempting to do is go through every row in a .csv file that I have and see if it has a value in it or not. Then, if it does have a value, I want to add that row to the Array at the bottom so that it will only print the rows that are filled in. How would I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't using for loop instead if-statements?

Comment: you probably would like to change your list to brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`

Comment: also lists and arrays are different.

Comment: Is this an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) or a list? Instead of so much code for your attempt to do whatever (which is not at all the right way to do it), please post more context and description of what you want to do. Post what `row` is, and your expected output.

Comment: That said, thank you for posting your code; it shows you have made an attempt and demonstrates what needs correcting.

Comment: If you didn't care about the printing you could do this in one line: myList = list(filter(lambda r:r, row))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to iterate over each row in your array, like so:

```
myList = []

for i, val in enumerate(row):  #[1]
    if val:                    #[2]
        myList.append(val)
        print 'row[%d] has a value' % i #[3]
    else:
        print 'row[%d] does not have a value' % i #[4]

print myList
```

Let's break this code down, so you learn and understand what's happening.

**The Loop**
 In the for loop, at reference `#[1]` -  [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) will give you the element of the list (in this case, we are calling it `val`), as well as the index (in this case, we assign it to variable `i`).

You could also just do `for val in row:` but I used `enumerate` here so you print the index of each row, as you did in your original code.

**The if statement**
The `if` statement, at reference `#[2]` just uses `if val:`. This will check if the variable `val` has a value that is not `null` and not empty. It is a cleaner way to write the `if row[X] != ""` that you originally had, but they logically are the same.

**Printing and string formatting**
The `print` statements at ref `#[3] and #[4]` let you print without having to hard code the rows. The `%d` serves as a place holder in a string for a digit, which is then defined after the string and the `%` operator. In this case, we've put the variable `i` there (which is the current index of `row` being accessed).

Continuing on the `print` statements, what I wrote is the same as having:
`print 'row[' + i + '] has a value'`
it's just a little cleaner.

There's also a new suggested way to do this, the python [`string format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). In this case you'd have:
`print 'row[{}] has a value"'.format(i)`

Hopefully this helps, and sorry if I went overboard, I assumed you were new to `Python` do to your hardcoding strings and having so many `if`s. If anything is unclear, just ask

Comment: I think you mean `if val` rather than `if ele`.